# GWT Textbox embadding with image

Tags: css, gwt

I am using GWT-Textbox and I want to add image at the right-hand side of the textbox.Is it possible to add an image in the textbox field ? please provide the code if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a CSS class.

`.searchBox{
background-image:url('graphics/magnifying-glass.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: right;
padding-right:5px;
}`

Then

`TextBox textBox = new TextBox();`

`textBox.setStyleName("searchBox");`

It should render like

[image: Textbox with Image on Right Corner]

Answer (score 0):

Give style as shown below:

```
background-image: url(Log-buttonred.bmp);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
```